# AngularFire2 getting started - cannot reach firestore backed

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have tried to follow the guide at https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md but i keep getting "cannot reach firestore backed".

I have no problem when i try to do a similar tutorial with vanillaJS, so i am pretty sure my environment settings are correct.

My firebase db rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase, 'vmspil'),
    AngularFirestoreModule 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li class="text" *ngFor="let item of items | async">
        {{item.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
`,
  styles: []
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  items: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.items = db.collection('text').valueChanges();
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "firebase-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.7",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^5.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i hadn't enabled the Cloud storage